# PHP 5 : move_uploaded_file returns FALSE

Tags: php, php-5.2

I have this code:

```
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

And I got with     `print_r($_FILES);`

```
Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => 008f7f52-9087-40a0-9ec7-557a632cd320.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpNgZGh2 [error] => 0 [size] => 22355 ) )
```

I'm not sure, but I think this isn't save the file to images folder. [I searched for the error 0 and I got nothing](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). The folder have the permission rwxrwxrwx. What could be wrong, how can I resolve this, and why I got this?

Comment: Have you tried providing an absolute path to the images folder on your server such as `dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/';`?

Comment: @Peter Featherstone Yes, also the same thing.